# Is it possible to replace a char using Linq in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linq

I need to replace a char by another char in a word. I know, we can use Replace method and can write own logic. But in my project, it takes too long time because i'm having large data. So i thought, it can be achieved by using Linq query as same as C#. But i don't know how to achieve this in JavaScript?

below is C# code:

```
string output = new String(input.Select(ch => ch == '2' ? '0' : ch).ToArray());
```

Please anyone guide me to achieve this in JS.

Thanks.

Comment: Linq is only available in C# but you can get quite close with packages like Lodash for JavaScript. Does that help? Edit: I should say is only available in .Net (VB, F#,C#...)

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have LINQ because that’s a .NET thing. But… I can’t imagine `replace` is much slower than that C#? How are you using it, how long does it take, and how big is your string?

Comment: `But in my project, it takes too long time because i'm having large data.` you're doing it wrong, show the code that *takes too long* - at least then it doesn't look like you're just after free coding from the coding monkeys - note, the equivalent in javascript is `let output = input.split('').map(v => v === '2' ? '0' : v).join('')` - but you wouldn't do it that way, surely

Comment: How large is your data?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX
i have used like "text.replace(/[$]/g,a)" . Is it wrong?

Comment: @Prithiv: It’s not wrong, but it shouldn’t be slow.

Comment: yes, because `[$]` matches `$` not `2`, and what is `a`?

Comment: large data means, i'm having more texts to replace in my document.

Comment: is large 100 characters? 1000000000000000 characters? or somewhere in between?

Comment: "a" means --> '$' should be replaced by 'a'

Comment: so, `text.replace(/[$]/g, "a")` - not what you wrote, right? is it any faster to do `text.replace(/\$/g, "a")`

Comment: i did same as in your comment. i just made typo mistake in my comment. but not in my project

Comment: so .. how big is this string ... I just tried a string that's 29,000,000 long and there's no issue (under 300ms)

Comment: for example, let assume in my project, text length is 1000, and  200000 words.

Comment: Far out ... how long is each word (this is like pulling teeth!!!) still 200000 words is maybe 1,000,000 characters, and 29,000,000 characters doesn't even bother firefox on a 7 year old intel CPU - which browser is "too slow"?

Comment: `text length is 1000, and 200000 words` ... what the!!! what does that mean ... how can text be 1000 length with 200000 words?